# Are there advantages of Python3 type hints over Python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, type-hinting

As I understand it, Python2 had a type hint convention which resembled:

```
def geo_series(r, n) # type: (float, int) -> float
  return (1-r**n)/(1-r)
```

This has been replaced with Python3's system which looks like:

```
def geo_series(r: float, n: int) -> float:
  return (1-r**n)/(1-r)
```

My question is: what is the advantage of the Python3 system over that of Python2? It seems to me that they contain equivalent information. Since the type-checking is done by an external tool anyway, I see no major disadvantage to putting the type-hint in a comment.

Am I missing something? My best guess is that there are situations in which you can create some wacky type which makes the python3 type-checking more informative than the equivalent python2?

Comment: The hints are closer to the variables, which makes them easier to read and write.

Comment: `# type: (float, int) -> float`  is a comment which may or may not have been interpreted by the IDE more specifically.  Type annotations are part of the code.

Comment: annotations can be retrieved at runtime by *any* code. Comments are usually stripped out, so are only seen by code that actually reads the `.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick mentioned in the comments, type annotations are part of the code, which means they can be accessed programmatically. For instance, in your python 3 example, you can use

```py
>>> geo_series.__annotations__
{'r': float, 'n': int, 'return': float}
```

This programmatic access makes it possible to dynamically type check functions if you want to implement that.

An example of annotations being used within code is the `dataclasses` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). A field in a dataclass is detected based on whether it has a type annotation, which is only possible if the annotations are part of the code instead of in a comment.